# 3ware raid controller update

Tags: linux, graphical-user-interface, 3ware

I can't find any fresh information about the `tw_cli` package for CentOS (or RHEL; its the same I guess).

I can't use the web interface because of strong certificate requirements. The only way to use the web UI was using IE but right now I see IE redirect everything to Edge which is affected by the deprecation mentioned.

My installed one has version 2.00.11.022 and my controller is 9650SE-2LP. I hope an update would fix the certificate feature. Does anyone know how I can get a newer version of this package? I need the web UI to be able to administer the attached storage.

Comment: What is your question? How to update the firmware? What RHEL/CentOS release are you running?

Comment: You are right I did not told my problem, I need to update my local package but I'm not finding a fresh one. I guess I'm not the first who runs into this issue since IE is death and current browsers have this vaidation as core function

Comment: So, the real question is: "where to find recent versions of tw_cli for RHEL/CentOS"? Sadly, that's off topic; such answers obsolete rather quickly. That said, your version seems to be pretty recent, there is no "newer" version. And, why wouldn't you use the CLI, why depending on the web interface so much?

Comment: I often avoid the gui version, this time I'm preferring it because I have successfully rebuilt  my array at the beginning when I tested a disk failure phisically changing one of them, I have written documentation of all the procedure. I'm using this computer as server for my core business I can't work without it and it's critical keep working without documentation on the cli version when I will have a disk failure. I must have to find new time to test and take notes of the command to rebuild and deploy the new array, so I thought I can save time and try to have back a working gui version.